# Set CSS variable in JS only for tag with attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-variables

I have an app that is in light mode and dark mode. I would like to dynamically set a variable for dark mode only. The issue I'm currently having is the dynamic variable is being set for both light mode and dark mode.

Here is an example:

```js
$('#theme-btn').on('click', function() {
  //simple check if light then turn dark, and vice-versa 
  if($('html').attr('theme') === 'light') {
    $('html').attr('theme', 'dark');
  } else {
    $('html').attr('theme', 'light');
  }
})

$('#change-dark').on('click', function() {

  //set new dark mode primary color
  let dark_color = "#FF48C9"
    $("html[theme='dark']").get(0).style.setProperty("--primary", dark_color);

})
```

```css
html[theme="light"] {
  --primary: #f6f6f6;
}

html[theme="dark"] {
  --primary: #121212;
}

.background {
  background: var(--primary);
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html theme="light">
<body>

<div class="background"></div>

<button id="theme-btn">Change theme</button>
<button id="change-dark">Dynamically change dark mode color</button>

</body>
</html>
```

To test:

1. Click on `Change theme` button several times.
2. When on light mode, try clicking `Dynamically change dark mode color`.. Error should occur
3. Next, change to dark mode, now click `Dynamically change dark mode color`.. Dynamic variable gets set.
4. Change to light mode, and dynamic variable is set for both light and dark mode...

How can I get the dynamic variable to ONLY change for dark mode.

If anyone has any ideas, that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a second CSS custom property, one which gets adjusted when the button is clicked, and have `--primary` use *either* that custom property (if it's valid) - or, if not valid, the original color (of `#121212`):

```
html[theme="light"] {
  --primary: var(--primary-light-custom, #f6f6f6);
}

html[theme="dark"] {
  --primary: var(--primary-dark-custom, #121212);
              /*   ^^^ used if valid     ^^^^^^ fallback value */
}
```

```
$("html").get(0).style.setProperty("--primary-dark-custom", dark_color);
```

```js
$('html').attr('theme', 'light'); // to properly emulate your markup
      // in this Stack Snippet

$('#theme-btn').on('click', function() {
  //simple check if light then turn dark, and vice-versa 
  $('html').attr('theme',
    $('html').attr('theme') === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
  );
})

$('#change-dark').on('click', function() {
  //set new dark mode primary color
  let dark_color = "#FF48C9"
  $("html").get(0).style.setProperty("--primary-dark-custom", dark_color);

})
```

```css
html[theme="light"] {
  --primary: var(--primary-light-custom, #f6f6f6);
}

html[theme="dark"] {
  --primary: var(--primary-dark-custom, #121212);
}

.background {
  background: var(--primary);
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background"></div>

<button id="theme-btn">Change theme</button>
<button id="change-dark">Dynamically change dark mode color</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider an extra variable so you can easily manage both independently

```js
$('#theme-btn').on('click', function() {
  //simple check if light then turn dark, and vice-versa 
  if($('html').attr('theme') === 'light') {
    $('html').attr('theme', 'dark');
  } else {
    $('html').attr('theme', 'light');
  }
})

$('#change-dark').on('click', function() {
  //set new dark mode primary color
  let dark_color = "#FF48C9"
    $("html").get(0).style.setProperty("--dark", dark_color);

})
```

```css
html[theme="light"] {
  --primary: var(--light,#f6f6f6);
}

html[theme="dark"] {
  --primary:var(--dark,#121212);
}


.background {
  background: var(--primary);
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html theme="light">
<body>

<div class="background"></div>

<button id="theme-btn">Change theme</button>
<button id="change-dark">Dynamically change dark mode color</button>

</body>
</html>
```